# How is model Meta class different from model form Meta class?

Tags: django-models, django-forms, metaclass

I wanted to understand the metaclasses we use in the model. I found about it in docs. I remember adding metaclass in model forms as well. It seems like model metaclass and model form metaclass is different. How are they different and what are the meta options in the model form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Epistemology, *meta* is a (ancient) Greek word means *about*. It is thus a class that says something *about* the model, or the `ModelForm`. The name is basically the only thing they have in common.

The `Meta` class of a model will specify the verbose name, etc. of a model, constraints and indexes defined in the corresponding database table, etc. The Django documentation has a [section that lists all the `Meta` options for a model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/#model-meta-options).

The `Meta` of a `ModelForm` on the other hand will explain to the `ModelForm` how it should construct a form for the given model. Normally it the `Meta` one defines the model for which the `ModelForm` is constructed together with the `fields` or `exclude` that specify what fields to include/exclude respectively. Furthermore the [*Overriding default fields* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelforms-overriding-default-fields) lists all other `Meta` options, where a user can (slightly) alter the way how the fields are defined in the `ModelForm`. The [source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/4.0.x/django/forms/models.py#L201-L211) also lists all the options for the `Meta` of `ModelForm`:

> ```
> class ModelFormOptions:
>     def __init__(self, options=None):
>         self.model = getattr(options, 'model', None)
>         self.fields = getattr(options, 'fields', None)
>         self.exclude = getattr(options, 'exclude', None)
>         self.widgets = getattr(options, 'widgets', None)
>         self.localized_fields = getattr(options, 'localized_fields', None)
>         self.labels = getattr(options, 'labels', None)
>         self.help_texts = getattr(options, 'help_texts', None)
>         self.error_messages = getattr(options, 'error_messages', None)
>         self.field_classes = getattr(options, 'field_classes', None)
> ```